# É bom utilizar variáveis globais por uma maior legibilidade no código?

Tags: c, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou a implementar um exercício do livro dos Deitel, How to Program C, 6a edição, o problema do Logo no capítulo 6. Foi uma questão interessante com problemas lógicos legais etc. A única dúvida de implementação pode parecer muito primária, mas realmente me deixou pensativo. Devo colocar variáveis globais por troca de um código legível?

Os exemplos abaixo demonstram a dúvida, que ainda utiliza outra variável global `matrix`, que infelizmente não pode ser local. Sei que é uma dúvida principiante, mas eu realmente não sei como proceder neste caso. Abaixo exemplifico minha dúvida:

Nota: Como o código ficou um pouco grande postei um "esboço"

**Exemplo com `enum` global:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SIZE 25

/*variável global necessária para que as funções escrevam na matriz */
char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]; 

/* Aqui enum é global podendo ser utilizado nas funções*/
enum direction {DOWN, RIGHT, UP, LEFT};

..."Protótips de funções" ... 

int main(void){

..."Aqui utiliza-se DOWN, RIGHT , UP, LEFT" ...

 return 0;
 }

 void funcaoExemplo(int var){

     if(var == DOWN) ...  

     ... "e utilizam-se também as outras variáveis de enum"
     ... "como RIGTH , UP e LEFT."
 }
```

O segundo caso é com enum dentro da função main:
**Exemplo com `enum` local:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SIZE 25

/*variável global necessária para que as funções escrevam na matriz */
char matrix[SIZE][SIZE]; 

..."Protótips de funções" ... 

int main(void){

/* Aqui enum é local podendo ser utilizado somente em main*/
enum direction {DOWN, RIGHT, UP, LEFT};

..."Aqui utiliza-se DOWN, RIGHT , UP, LEFT" ...

 return 0;
 }

 void funcaoExemplo(int var){

     if(var == 0) ... /* equivalendo a DOWN */ 

     ... "aqui se utilizam os valores correspondentes" 
     ... "como 1 , 2 e 3 no lugar de RIGTH , UP e LEFT respectivamente"
 }
```

Como devo proceder?

1. Coloco esse `enum` em escopo global como no primeiro exemplo?
2. Faço como no segundo exemplo declarando um `enum` somente em main, e nas funções que o utilizam faço substituição por seus valores inteiros?
3. O insiro `enum` em `main` e em todas funções que o utilizam?
4. Não utilizo `enum`, e faço valer somente seus respectivos inteiros?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normalmente é oposto, variáveis globais afetam negativamente a legibilidade. Embora possa parecer o contrário para iniciantes principalmente vendo exemplos muito limitados.

Exemplos de livros e tutoriais normalmente não se preocupam muito com a legibilidade do código, até porque o código costuma ser muito pequeno e nestes casos a legibilidade não é tão afetada assim. Mas geram um mal costume.

1. Enumerações não são variáveis, são declarações de estruturas de dados, portanto elas devem ser globais mesmo. A não ser que elas só sejam usadas localmente - o que é bem raro. Note que uma enumeração possui membros e não variáveis. Estes membros são símbolos e não variam nada. No máximo podem ser chamados de constantes.
2. Não faz. Até pode fazer mas não faz sentido.
3. Não insere localmente em nenhuma função se a utilização é global.
4. O `enum` será sempre recomendado nestes casos. Não use [números mágicos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Não há nada que impeça o uso da variável `matrix` como local. Esta sim deveria deixar de ser global. Ela deveria ser passada como parâmetro entre as funções.

Existe um outro problema nesta abordagem. Se o livro ensina assim, está ensinando errado isto e provavelmente ensinará outras coisas de forma errada. Então se prepare para aprender errado.

O C faz *casting* automático em muitas situações e não reclama mas o correto seria comparar dois tipos exatamente iguais. Ou seja não deveria comparar um inteiro com uma enumeração (funciona porque a enumeração cai para um inteiro automaticamente) mas essas variável `var` deveria ser do tipo `direction`. Pode parecer que não faz diferença mas legibilidade exige que passe a intenção correta.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

enum direction { DOWN, RIGHT, UP, LEFT };

void funcaoExemplo(enum direction var) {
    if(var == DOWN) printf("%d", RIGHT); //só para testar
}

int main(void){
    funcaoExemplo(DOWN);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/PWGItc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Encapsulating). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Encapsulating.c).

Comment: Realmente eu não sabia que podia passa enumerações para funções. Vou tentar tirar `matrix` do escopo global e passá-la como parâmetro para funções, já que matrizes inteiras são passadas por referência deve ser fácil implementar.

Comment: Pode passar qualquer tipo de dado. No fundo você está passando um `int`. Não estou dizendo que não deva usar ma em C uma enumeração tem pouca vantagem real. Ela deixa o código mais legível mas a linguagem não ajuda usar de um jeito melhor. Em C++ e outras linguagens mais modernas a enumeração é tipada de fato e o compilador pode detectar erros.

Comment: Na verdade tirei a enumeração do código, pois tendo que tratá-las como você descreve, eu teria que fazer alterações significativas, pois eu estava literalmente fazendo contas com os valores de cada uma, pois há uma função que "rotaciona" tal valores para mudança de direção. O único problema é que a enumeração dava uma legibilidade maior ao código, mas eu posso conviver com isso.